# Singapore extended visit

Tags: visas, us-citizens, singapore

How long can one stay in Singapore without requiring a work visa or other such accommodation? Could you, for example, sublet an apartment for a summer, or even a year, and have access to insured medical services or other necessities during that time?

**Edit:** In response to the first comment I will attempt to clarify. I guess what I'm asking is how long does a tourist visa last, how many times can it be extended and how hard is that to do? Additionally, I am from the US.

Comment: Apologies for my n00b-ness, obviously I've never really traveled outside my country much so I'm not even sure what to ask. I'll edit the question to address your comment.

Comment: So why do you actually want to stay in Singapore for a year?  Work, girlfriend, something else...?  There are likely better ways than a string of tourist visas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your profile, I am guessing you are a US citizen.  You get a 90 day Visit Pass when you enter Singapore and you can apply to extend it for another 90 days (S$40 extension fee plus S$30 visa fee as you would exceed your 90 day visa free period - http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=180&secid=178).

But as a tourist you are not covered under Singapore's health coverage, as that is for citizens and expats with resident status.  On the bright side, medical costs in Singapore are lower than back in the states and the level of care quite good.

Comment: Can it only be extended once?

Comment: Yes, you can only extend it once.  If you are contemplating a longer stay it is better to get a proper visa from the Singapore Embassy before traveling.

Answer (score 1):

In addition I'd like to point people to the following link: [Visa Policy of Singapore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Singapore)

Western countries appear to be VISA free currently with either 30 or 90 day Visa's.  If you want to save some money, you can simply travel to Malaysia by bus and returned to get another 30 (or 90?) days. I've done this several times although it might be best to stay a few days in the other country, I've returned on the same day before.

To travel to JB by bus the easiest way is to take the MRT to Woodlands terminal.  Then take bus number 950 to JB.  Don't forget to bring your passport.  You can hop on the same bus number to return.

Comment: This is called a visa run and Immigration *will* start asking hard questions after doing this a few times.  You're better off doing the 90 days plus extension thing, or getting a long-term visa for the actual reason you want to stay.